# Scroll till bottom using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I'm using Selenium with Python to extract list of doctors from [this](https://www.dukemedicine.org/find-doctors-physicians/) website. I select the option **Specialty** and extract the results. The results are displayed once we scroll the pages as in twitter feed. I'm unable to scroll the page to view the results. I tried multiple approaches like **send_keys** as:

```
   for i in range(0,15):
                self.driver.find_element_by_id("doctor-matrix-section").send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
                time.sleep(1)
                print 'hello'
                print i
                i+= 1
```

The loop is used as i've no idea how long i need to press the **PAGE DOWN** button. 
I also tried another approach as:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

None of the approach i followed worked. Any help would be really useful.

Comment: Did you try - `driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` ? scrollTo is used when you have specific coordinates in your webpage. scrollBy scrolls by the number of pixels that you give in like `document.body.scrollHeight`.

Comment: i tried it but not working at all, the site is developed using angularjs , does that affects anyhow ?

Answer (score 2):

The site you have referenced is loading very slowly for me and is difficult to test for your specific application. One way I have been able to scroll in infinite loading scenarios in the past is to use selenium to select the body and send it the spacebar keypress.

```
bg = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body')

bg.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```

You might want to try using this in a `for i in range(x)` loop to achieve the desired length of scroll.

Comment: Pressing space only once won't get you to the bottom of it if the page is long. and you don't know the value of x when you say put this in loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the answer you're looking for:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

elem = self.driver.find_element_by_id("doctor-matrix-section")
elem.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

This will lead to end of the webpage in one go only.